# X-Bee Transmitter sending same data without refreshing

Tags: arduino, xbee

I'm having a difficult time with default code from Colorado Space Grant and Symposium. I want to ask you guys first because it is difficult to get a hold of them sometimes because it is mainly three people in the organization. My problem is that in making a beacon and rover system they have us using Xbees and Arduino Fios. There code has us take a compass reading at the beacon and send that to the rover so it can compare the beacon heading to it's heading. Our transmitter appears to not be refreshing so the same packet is sent continuously without changing. Is this a common problem? If so, how have you dealt with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can check at the sampling rate, set the sampling rate to a certain value and not to zero. To check either you have received the correct packet, each packet should start with 7E in hexadecimal. The packet has 24 bytes. You can read data obtained from the beacon at byte 22 and 23 if you are using analog digital converter and you can read on digital pins from byte 20 and 21.